# Issue with SQLite query comparing two casted values

Tags: sqlite

I'm having a little issue with a query in SQLite and I hope one of you guys might be able to help me out.

I need to create a query that will only show me the results above a specific value. It is essentially a select * from table where a > b

Now the issue I'm facing is that although the values are in a column which is of the decimal type, the values appear to be strings. And the value that I want to compare against will be coming from a string.

The database is not one I own or populate, I just have read access.

values that I'm trying to sort are

```
26,4
18,2
11,1
11,1
10,6
2,8
2,8
2,1
0,0
0,0
0,0
1,7
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,2
0,0
0,0
1,8
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,1
0,0
10,0
```

When I use a query such as

> select * FROM [table] WHERE CAST(GR14 as double) > CAST('1,0' as
>   double)

The result I get is

```
26,4
18,2
11,1
11,1
10,6
2,8
2,8
2,1
10,0
```

The results 1,7 and 1,8 are missing.

I have tried casting as float, real, decimal but the result stays always the same.

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks,
Kenneth

Comment: Yes but the query is > 1,0 which means he should be finding 1,7 and 1,8. They are decimal values

Comment: Yeah, my bad ... have you tried using a `dot` instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strange issue is due to how SQLite interprets numbers with a comma instead of a period as the decimal point:

```
sqlite> select cast('1,7' as double);
cast('1,7' as double)
1.0
sqlite> select cast('1.7' as double);
cast('1.7' as double)
1.7
```

In lieu of this being fixed in SQLite, I'd suggest doing a text replacement of the text column, THEN casting it to a double:

```
select * FROM [table] WHERE CAST(replace(GR14, ',','.') as double) > CAST('1,0' as double)
```

*Noted for posterity: SQLite version 3.22.0*

Comment: I was thinking the same and I have tried it but it didn't seem to work either. Although it might have been my query? What Query should I use to replace the value?